# Use generics in AddTransient method in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

Using Asp.Net Core I have the following:

```
services.AddTransient<Context>(x => new Context("my connection", new ContextMapper()));
```

I would like to use an extension method and generics so I created:

```
public static void AddContext<T1, T2>(this IServiceCollection services, String connectionString) 
    where T1 : IDbContext 
    where T2 : DbContextMapper {

  T2 contextMapper = (T2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T2));

  T1 context = (T1)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T1), new Object[] { connectionString, contextMapper });

  services.AddTransient<T1>(x => context);

}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
The type 'T1' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TService' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddTransient<TService>(IServiceCollection, Func<IServiceProvider, TService>)'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [constrain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) a type parameter to be a reference type use the `class` type constraint.  EG

```
where T1 : class, IDbContext
```

But why are you adding the DbContext as Transient instead of Scoped?

Comment: Context is a class with a property of type ILiteDatabase from https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB. I though Transient would be the correct option. Should I use Scoped? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure.  Transient is safe, but a single request might use multiple different instances.  Entity Framework typically uses Scoped.

Comment: The reason why I used transient it was because the data comes from a file. I will try both transient and scope and see what happens. Thank you for the answer. I just accepted.